# Predicting nature of Result object returned by using ArcGIS geoprocessing tool in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, geoprocessing-framework, result-object

In the [Code Sample from the ArcGIS Pro help for the ArcPy class named Geometry](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/geometry.htm#C_GUID-BC466D06-360C-42BD-B198-DA4139B45F49) there is something that catches my attention:

```
# Run the Copy Features tool, setting the output to the geometry object.
# geometries is returned as a list of geometry objects.
geometries = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("c:/data/streets.shp",
                                           arcpy.Geometry())
```

Here the Result object (`geometries`) returned by running arcpy.CopyFeatures_management() is a list of Geometry objects, which is very useful for subsequent processing in that sample code.

However, other than by coming across this sample code, is there any way that I could have learned what that Result object would be?

I have reviewed what I think are the two most obvious places to look in the ArcGIS Pro help:

- [Copy Features](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/copy-features.htm)
- [Result](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/result.htm)

I *think* it may be hinted at in the [Result](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/result.htm) documentation where it says that the Return Value is:

> The output, either as a recordset or a string.
>
> If the output of the tool, such as MakeFeatureLayer is a layer,
>   getOutput will return a Layer object.
>
> Result outputs can also be accessed by index, so result.getOutput(0)
>   and result[0] are equivalent.

but I was/am hoping to gain a clearer understanding.

Comment: What's the confusion? Are you trying to predict the *geometry type* (point, line, polygon...) or predict that the *result object* is a list of geometries? You can get the geometry *type* from the geometry http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/geometry.htm to decide if you have points/lines/polygons etc but what does type(geometries) return? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225038/determine-the-type-of-an-object

Comment: @MichaelStimson I'm trying to "predict that the result object is a list of geometries" (probably by having some documentation to read).  For example, I thought a search of the CopyFeatures page on 'result' or 'return' might jump to something that says it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Result` object returned from arcpy functions is a bit ambiguous as it is just a 'Geoprocessing Result' and the output data depends on the function ran. If you want to know what the output data is, you can do this a few ways:

```
# via type, result is output from an arcpy tool
print(type(result.getOutput(0)))

# via it's class 
print(result.getOutput(0).__class__)

# when the tool returns multiple outputs
print([result.getOutput(i) for i in range(result.outputCount)])
```

Type checking is useful when you need to do something based on a type.  This could be especially useful with your example of getting geometries, which could be one of many types:

```
# do geometry checks
geometries = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("c:/data/streets.shp",
                                           arcpy.Geometry())
for geometry in geometries:
    # check for point
    if isinstance(geometry, arcpy.Point):
        print('it is a point')
    elif isinstance(geometry, arcpy.Polygon):
        print('it is a polygon)

    # do checks for polygon and multipoint too

    # check if null geometry (will be None)
    elif not isinstance(geometry, arcpy.Geometry): #base class for all geometries
        raise TypeError('Null geometry detected')
```

Also useful for making sure you are getting a valid type that you expect from a tool (using [arcpy.Describe](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/describe.htm) could also be useful for the output):

```
# check if output is a layer
lyr = arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer(r'\\server\some_data\test.shp', 'test').getOutput(0)

if isisntance(lyr, arcpy.mapping.Layer):
    # do something with layer
else:
    raise TypeError('did not return a valid layer!')
```

Getting at `Result` objects is also useful in custom tools.  Any output's returned from the tool via the [arcpy.SetParameter(index, value)](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/setparameter.htm) (or maybe even a function return statement?) can also be collected the same way.

Comment: I think "The `Result` object returned from arcpy functions is a bit ambiguous as it is just a 'Geoprocessing Result' and the output data depends on the function ran." sums up why I felt my comprehension was missing something.  To me it seems as if the documentation for every tool needs another section to describe what will be returned if a `Result` object gets set to it.

Comment: I agree, that would be really helpful.

Comment: Yes, the documentation is a little scant on *what* a GPResult object is and how/if it can be used.. only functions like GetCount where the result 
object is directly used in the examples have any sort of documentation. Perhaps it's some sort of *secret handshake* for developers - there's a few in ArcObjects, if you don't know they're there you'd miss them altogether.